# $p_0^2 + q_0^2 = 1$ and $-\sin(s) = -p_0\sin(s) + q_0\cos(s)$ $\rightarrow $ $p_0 = -\cos2s, q_0 = -\sin(2s)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How does solving $p_0^2 + q_0^2 = 1$ and $-\sin(s) = -p_0\sin(s) + q_0\cos(s)$ give $p_0 = -\cos2s $ and $q_0 = -\sin(2s)$?

I can clearly see one solution is $p_0=1,q_0=0$ but can't seem to understand the other.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** : Let  $p_0=\cos x $ and $q_0=\sin x$. Then the second equation becomes  $$-\sin s = -\cos x\sin s + \sin x\cos s.$$
That is 
$$-\sin s =  \sin(x-s).$$
Now solve for $x$.

Comment: I still cant seem to do it

Comment: Another hint:$\sin A+\sin B=0 \iff 2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2=0$. This means either $\sin\frac{A+B}2=0$ or $\cos\frac{A-B}2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $p_0^2 + q_0^2 = 1$,  there is $\theta$ such that $p_0 = \cos(\theta)$ and $q_0 = \sin(\theta)$.  Thus your equation becomes
$$ \sin(-s) = -\sin(s) = - \cos(\theta) \sin(s) + \sin(\theta) \cos(s) = \sin(\theta - s)$$
Thus either $\theta = 2 n \pi$ or $\theta = (2n+1)\pi + 2 s$.